# Creating a form that outputs a string into a textarea with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to javascript but I'm trying to create a simple program that makes formatting sources for the blog I edit very easy. I want the information that users type into the form to be printed out into the textarea. Here's what I have so far:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function writeCode() {
            var src1 = document.getElementById('src1').value;
                // src2 = document.getElementbyId('src2'),
                // src3 = document.getElementbyId('src3'),
                // src4 = document.getElementbyId('src4'),
                // src5 = document.getElementbyId('src5'),
                // src6 = document.getElementbyId('src6'),
                // src7 = document.getElementbyId('src7'),
                // src8 = document.getElementbyId('src8'),
                // src9 = document.getElementbyId('src9'),
                // src10 = document.getElementbyId('src10'),
            var lnk1 = document.getElementById('lnk1').value;
                // lnk2 = document.getElementbyId('lnk2'),
                // lnk3 = document.getElementbyId('lnk3'),
                // lnk4 = document.getElementbyId('lnk4'),
                // lnk5 = document.getElementbyId('lnk5'),
                // lnk6 = document.getElementbyId('lnk6'),
                // lnk7 = document.getElementbyId('lnk7'),
                // lnk8 = document.getElementbyId('lnk8'),
                // lnk9 = document.getElementbyId('lnk9'),
                // lnk10 = document.getElementbyId('lnk10');

            outputValue = '<span style="color: #888888; font-size: xx-small;">Sources: </span>' + '<a href=' + lnk1 + 'target="_blank"><span style="color: #2200fc; font-size: xx-small;">' + src1 + '</span></a>'

            document.outputArea.value = outputValue;
        }
        console.log(writeCode);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p></p>
    <form name="sources">
        Source 1 <input type="text" id="src1"/>
            Link 1 <input type="text" id="lnk1"/></br>
        Source 2 <input type="text" id="src2"/>
            Link 2 <input type="text" id="lnk2"/></br>
        Source 3 <input type="text" id="src3"/>
            Link 3 <input type="text" id="lnk3"/></br>
        Source 4 <input type="text" id="src4"/>
            Link 4 <input type="text" id="lnk4"/></br>
        Source 5 <input type="text" id="src5"/>
            Link 5 <input type="text" id="lnk5"/></br>
        Source 6 <input type="text" id="src6"/>
            Link 6 <input type="text" id="lnk6"/></br>
        Source 7 <input type="text" id="src7"/>
            Link 7 <input type="text" id="lnk7"/></br>
        Source 8 <input type="text" id="src8"/>
            Link 8 <input type="text" id="lnk8"/></br>
        Source 9 <input type="text" id="src9"/>
            Link 9 <input type="text" id="lnk9"/></br>
        Source 10 <input type="text" id="src10"/>
            Link 10 <input type="text" id="lnk10"/></br>
        <input type="button" value="Write my code!" onclick="writeCode();"/></br>
        <textarea style="width:600px;height:300px;" name="outputArea" id="outputArea"></textarea>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I get an error saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'outputArea' of undefined on line 28" when I run the code. How can I resolve this? Again, I'm very new to js, so sorry for any ignorance.

I also eventually want to be able to output only data that has been entered. How would I do this? Would I use a for loop, or some other method?

Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind! I changed "document.outputArea.value = outputValue;" to "            document.getElementById('outputArea.value') = outputValue;" and it worked fine. I'd still like to know the best way to output only data that has been entered though, so I'll leave this up for now.

Comment: Have you tried `document.getElementById('outputArea').value`? And for ignoring any sources that haven't been entered, you could look into onChange events for textfields, or if statements.

Comment: I'm slightly skeptical of `document.getElementById('outputArea.value')` working. Is that your actual code? If that does work, that's pretty cool

Comment: You're right. I used "document.getElementById('outputArea').value" ... sorry for the typo!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this ***document.getElementById('outputArea').value = outputValue;***

Comment: Thanks, Greg. Worked perfectly.